# Fix top Row in Data table in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a data table that scrolls horizontally and vertically due to the amount of data available. I want the top row which specifies the column names to always be visible when scrolling down.

code: No issues in the code I am getting the results, but when I scroll down The header wont be shown. Can any one help me in how to fix the header(1st row).

My header(1st row) elements keeps changing for each req, 
the way its implemented is there will be cards in my dashboard onclicking each card it hits the API and I am displaying its result i.e contents of field named header list as my first row.

Content of the header keeps changing for each card. so once any card is clicked new page containing its data will popup, there I need to fix the header.

```
Widget getTable(BuildContext context, var data) {
    Widget _widget;
    _widget = SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: DataTable(
          rows: createDataRows(context, data),
          columns: createDataColumns(context, data),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return _widget;
  }

  List<DataRow> createDataRows(BuildContext context, var jsonData) {
    List<DataRow> _dataRows = [];
    List<DataCell> _cells = [];
    String _dataCellTitle;

    Map<String, Object> headers = jsonData['headers'];
    Map<int, String> headerMapping;
    headerMapping = headers.keys
        .toList()
        .asMap()
        .map((index, value) => MapEntry(index + 1, value));

    if (jsonData["data"] == null) {
      _dataRows = [];
    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < jsonData["data"].length; j++) {
        _cells.add(DataCell(Text('${j + 1}')));
        for (int i = 1; i <= headerMapping.length; i++) {
          _dataCellTitle = "${jsonData["data"][j][headerMapping[i]]}" ?? '-';
          _cells.add(DataCell(Text('$_dataCellTitle')));
        }
        _dataRows.add(DataRow(cells: _cells));
        _cells = [];
      }
    }
    return _dataRows;
  }

  List<DataColumn> createDataColumns(BuildContext context, var jsonData) {
    String columnTitle;
    List<DataColumn> _dataColumns = [];
    Map<String, Object> headers = jsonData['headers'];
    Map<int, String> headerMapping;
    headerMapping = headers.keys
        .toList()
        .asMap()
        .map((index, value) => MapEntry(index + 1, value));
    _dataColumns.add(DataColumn(label: Text('S. No.')));
    for (int i = 1; i <= headerMapping.length; i++) {
      columnTitle = headers[headerMapping[i]];
      _dataColumns.add(
        DataColumn(label: Text('$columnTitle')),
      );
    }
    return _dataColumns;
  }
```

like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIuu7.png)

where the first row is constant and first column also.

Comment: I think you have to try with https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PaginatedDataTable-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do the smart thing here, You can create two datatables one with only column, and one with rows.

Suppose your `list_rows` is a List<DataRow> and `list_column` is List<DataColumn> of your actual columns, then:

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        DataTable(
          rows: [], // DONT PROVIDE ROWS
          columns: list_column, // PROVIDE YOUR COLUMNS HERE
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: DataTable(
                rows: list_lows, // PROVIDE ROWS HERE
                columns: List.generate(
                    list_column.length, (index) => DataColumn(label: Text(''))), // GENERATE EMPTY COLUMNS
                headingRowHeight: 0, // SHRINK THE HEADER
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

This way your columns will always be on top!

Comment: This is not working with the horizontal scroll

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution to make Datatable Header sticky :

```
              SizedBox(
                height: 500,
                width: 1000,
                child: Scrollbar(
                  controller: _vertical,
                  thumbVisibility: true,
                  trackVisibility: true,
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    controller: _horizontal,
                    thumbVisibility: true,
                    trackVisibility: true,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: _horizontal,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            controller: _vertical,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            child: DataTable(
                              rows: list_rows, // PROVIDE ROWS HERE
                              columns: List.generate(
                                list_column.length,
                                (index) => DataColumn(
                                  label: Text(''),
                                ),
                              ), //GENERATE EMPTY COLUMNS
                              headingRowHeight: 90, // HEADER HEIGHT
                            ),
                          ),
                          DataTable(
                            rows: [], // DONT PROVIDE ROWS
                            columns:
                                list_column, // PROVIDE YOUR COLUMNS HERE
                            headingRowHeight: 90, // HEADER HEIGHT
                            headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                              (states) => Color.fromRGBO(86, 153, 255, 1),
                            ),
                            border: TableBorder.all(
                                width: 1.0, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Cool solution. How did you solve the problem of both data tables have different spacing between labels?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you have one method `getTable` to get data content,
In it you are calling two methods

1) To fetch rows

2) To fetch columns.

But you didn't show the code of `DataTable` Widget.

I assume it is ListView or Column.

So in your DataTable Widget you should create one static `Row` for that heading.

```
ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('$heading1'),
            Text('$heading2'),
            Text('$heading3'),
          ],
        ),

        /// Your row and column

      ],
    );
```

With information you provided i assume it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I have Used Like that , and its working fine :

```
SingleChildScrollView dataBody() {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: DataTable(
                columnSpacing: 10,
                //sortAscending: sort,
                //sortColumnIndex: 0,
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Date"), numeric: false),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Particulars"), numeric: false),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Amount"), numeric: true)
                ],
                rows: transactions
                    .map((txn) => DataRow(cells: [
                          DataCell(
                            Text(
                              DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy').format(txn.date),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                            ),
                            /*onTap: () {
                          print('Selected ${txn.date}');
                        }*/
                          ),
                          DataCell(FittedBox(
                            child: Text(
                              txn.particulars,
                            ),
                          )),
                          DataCell(Text(txn.amount.toString()))
                        ]))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ));
      }
```

Comment: this thing not work